# Creating synchronized web and mobile app .What technologies to use

Tags: android, firebase, mobile, desktop-application

I need to create an app for managing appointments. I need to create a desktop app (for wondows xp and windows 10) and a mobile app (android) to manage the appointments when I'm not in the office. I want when I create or change an appointment from a device, the changes to be applied (the same time) to the other two devices (my devices are 2 pc and 1 android phone).

I know html,css,javascript, basic knowledge of java and pyhton.

What technologies do you suggest to use, for the desktop app, the mobile app, the database/server ?

ps: I'm thinkg to use javafx or electron for the desktop app, android java or flutter, or react native or pwa for the mobile app, and firebase for database/server the free version to reduce the costs (my business is small).

Also I'm available to learn a new technology in 1-2 months and apply it for my application.

I'm looking forward for your suggestions, thank you!

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site works best with specific programming questions. General **How do I?** which requires extensive answers or **What is Best?** is consider off-topic. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) Do realize that [Windows XP has been End of Life since 2014](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14223/windows-xp-end-of-support) and [Electron doesn't support XP](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5676) Please break down your needs and research.